# Mvc Id doesn't get submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a dropdown as seen below, trying to pass my id to controller but always comes as 0

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SagsTypersId, "SagsTypeId1", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("SagsTypeId1", null, htmlAttributes: new {
           @class = "selectpicker",
           data_show_subtext = "true",
           data_live_search = "true"
       })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SagsTypersId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

heres is my controller Get.

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {

        ViewBag.SagsTypeId1 = new SelectList(db.SagsTypers, "Id", "SagsTyper");

        return View();
    }
```

here is controller Post

```
 public ActionResult Create(Sag sag)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Sags.Add(sag);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        return View(sag);
    }
```

to sum it up, my issue is that the Sags.SagsTypersId is 0 when trying to submit. Can't seem to locate the error.

Best regards
Johnny.

Comment: `SagsTypersId` is not equal to `SagsTypeId1`! (use the strongly typed `DropDownListFor()` method - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SagsTypersId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.SagsTypeId1)`

Comment: oka i will try.

Comment: And then get rid of your `ViewBag` and do it correctly using a view model (refer [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o))

Answer (score 0):

You did not attach the dropdown list to the model, use `@Html.DropDownListFor` instead of `@Html.DropDownList`

where SagsTypersList is list contains SagsTypersID & SagsTyperName

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SagsTypersId, 
          new SelectList(SagsTypersList, "SagsTypersID", "SagsTyperName"), htmlAttributes: new {
           @class = "selectpicker",
           data_show_subtext = "true",
           data_live_search = "true"
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  @Html.DropDownList("SagsTypeId1", null, htmlAttributes: new {
           @class = "selectpicker",
           data_show_subtext = "true",
           data_live_search = "true"
       })
```

to

```
  @Html.DropDownList("SagsTypeId", null, htmlAttributes: new {
           @class = "selectpicker",
           data_show_subtext = "true",
           data_live_search = "true"
       })
```

**OR**
Simply use strongly typed html helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SagsTypersId, 
          new SelectList(SagsTypersList, "SagsTypersID", "SagsTyperName"), htmlAttributes: new {
           @class = "selectpicker",
           data_show_subtext = "true",
           data_live_search = "true"
       })
```

Comment: Thanks i ended up solving it like this:


@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SagsTypersId,
         (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.SagsTypeId1, htmlAttributes: new
          {
              @class = "selectpicker",
              data_show_subtext = "true",
              data_live_search = "true"
          })